# Add option to given spinner through AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

My app consists of multiple spinners to allow users to quickly fill out a form. I am trying to add a feature where if the user cannot find the best answer in a spinner, there is option at the bottom of the spinner labeled "add answer".

I understand how to register when "add answer" is clicked, and open a AlertDialog with a TextView entry:

```
case R.id.C1Lspin:     
            if(C1LSpin.getSelectedItem() == "Add Option..."){
                addOption(C1LAdapter); //call AlertDialog
            }
        break;
```

My issue is on return from the AlertDialog I am struggling to notify which list of spinner options should be updated. My instinct is to bundle the specific spinner's arrayAdapter so that when I override the AlertDialog positive button it can use the arrayAdapter that had been bundled.

Is there any way to bundle an arrayAdapter to be passed through an AlertDialog. I am also wondering if there is any other way to notify the override function of the AlertDialog so it know which Spinner arrayAdapter to update. I am planning on having about 10 spinners so I really don't want to create a specific AlertDialog for each spinner.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a class reference variable.
I set the reference before I start the asynchronous process, then on return from the process the reference variable is grabbed, then used, and set to null to avoid any data leak.

Not fancy or sleek but for now it works.